# Google Spreadsheet Inconsistent Datetime Format

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-dates

When we push date and time values to a google spreadsheet in the format d/m/Y H:i a (eg. 25/12/2015 1:43 pm) the date and time is displayed inconsistently, see below:
[image]

Any idea why the format is not consistent in google spreadsheets and how we can ensure it is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently you have a bug in the code that is forming those datetime strings: it always puts "pm" at the end. There is no such time as "15:39 pm", so Google does not parse this as a date time value, treating it just as a string (hence, left-align).

To fix  this, simply drop "pm" part, since you are evidently using 24-hour time rather than 12-hour. Better yet, use ISO formatting:

```
2015-11-13 15:39
```

which should be correctly parsed by Google Sheets independent of your locale.

Comment: I confirmed this with my own test.

Comment: Can't believe I missed that! Thank you